# Disable click outside of JQuery message box

Tags: jquery, messagebox

I want to Disable my outside background , view in Jquery Message box, im coded the following sampale. please give me a solution.
thanks.

```
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     @if (TempData["SuccessEdit"] != null)
    {
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#green").dialog();

            });
        </script>
    }

<div id="green">
    <p>Successully Updated</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just give this `modal: true` in your initialization:

```
$(function () {
  $("#green").dialog({
    modal: true
  });
});
```